# fadeout effect not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to load new data after fading out effect.

```
callback:function(data)
{
 parent.fadeOut('slow').delay(5000);
 $('#div_one').html(data);
 modal_message();
                                                            },

if i remove $('#div_one').html(data),
```

then fading effect will work.
but if i keep this sentence fading effect is not working

Answer (score 2):

Provide a callback function to `fadeOut` like this:

```
parent.fadeOut('slow', function(){
  // your code to load data
});
```